# move animation using cakeyframeanimation

Tags: cgpath, cakeyframeanimation

i attempt to create CAKeyframeAnimation in order to move image to achieve half of the curved path can any one help to create it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I am pretty familiar with keyframe animations, but you need to describe what you're trying to do.

Are you trying to move your image along a an arc created with CGPathAddArc? What shape do you want your image to follow, and what do you mean by "half of the curved path?"